# How to save recorded video into photo album?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Following code is to save image took from camera into photo album.

```
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) 
    {
         image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self,
                                       @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                       nil);
    }
```

How to save Recoded video into photoAlbum?

Comment: [UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check Below code...

```
   - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{



    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
       if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){        
               // Saving the video / // Get the new unique filename 
               NSString *sourcePath = [[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"]relativePath]; 
                  UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(sourcePath,nil,nil,nil);

}
```

Comment: i am Recording video. not taking from any file

Comment: where u using destination path

Comment: is it necessary to delete video at it's temporary path? (`/private/var/mobile/Applications/C2C16234-4535-4F0A-B22E-65C0F820AB25/tmp/capture-T0x1c50f840.tmp.uEJZZe/capturedvideo.MOV`)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)saveMovieToCameraRoll
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:movieURL
                                completionBlock:^(NSURL     *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                                    if (error)
                                        [self     showError:error];
                                    else
                                        [self     removeFile:movieURL];

                                        dispatch_async(movieWritingQueue, ^{
                                            recordingWillBeStopped = NO;
                                            self.recording = NO;

                                            [self.delegate recordingDidStop];
                                    });
                                }];
    [library release];
}
```

This is the code snippet from apple example rosywriter. Sould work.

```
        movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"Movie.MOV"]];
        [movieURL retain];
```

The above lines to create file and path  for the video.

```
- (void) startRecording
{
    dispatch_async(movieWritingQueue, ^{

        if ( recordingWillBeStarted || self.recording )
            return;

        recordingWillBeStarted = YES;

        // recordingDidStart is called from     captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection: once the asset writer is setup
        [self.delegate recordingWillStart];

        // Remove the file if one with the same name already exists
        [self removeFile:movieURL];

        // Create an asset writer
        NSError *error;
        assetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:movieURL fileType:(NSString *)kUTTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&error];
        if (error)
            [self showError:error];
    }); 
}
```

This function is used to start recording video into that movieURL file using avassetwriter.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
- (void)saveVideo:(NSURL *)videoUrl {
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoUrl];
    [videoData writeToFile:@"YOUR_PATH_HERE" atomically:YES];
  }    

  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
      NSString *type = [mediaDict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

      if ([type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo] || 
          [type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) { // movie != video
          NSURL *videoURL [mediaDict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
          [self saveVideo:videoUrl];
      }

  }
```

---

or you can try this also
Saving the video to the documents directory is as follows

```
   - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


  NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

  NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/vid1.mp4"];

  BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:tempPath atomically:NO];


  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
```