# Save any Video to Video folder of iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save recorded video into photo album?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991332/how-to-save-recorded-video-into-photo-album)

How can i save  Video to Video folder of iphone and Rename it.
Please anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work without jailbreak.

If you have Cydia store, then you'll find there a suitable App