# How to save video from document directory to gallery?

Tags: ios, photo-gallery

How to save video in document directory to gallery in iOS,here i downloaded video from server and saved in document directory and now i want to move it to gallery.

Comment: [UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum) and (http://stackoverflow.com/q/9991332/1059705)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(sourcePath,nil,nil,nil);
```

you can pass the sourcePath as

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

append your path or file name to get sourcePath.

```
NSString *sourcePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"youVideo.mp4"];
```

Comment: if i use these 2 lines of code will it work     NSString *sourcePath =[exportURL path];
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(sourcePath,nil,nil,nil);

Comment: you have to add source path as Nitin described in the below anser..see the edit

Comment: not possible this one code document directory save video to save gallery folder objective c .

Comment: any one know how to possible save video document directory to gallery folder objective c ?

Answer (score 4):

First you need to get particular video Path or Document directory like:-

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"youVideo.mp4"]; 
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]; 


 ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:movieURL
                            completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){/*notify of completion*/}];
```

Comment: this is not working for me

Comment: only save as crash video layer , any one know please let me know !